# ADB driver for spice android device Mi 425 not finding

Tags: android, adb

i m new to android and having a android device make name **SPICE** the model number **Mi425** with android **ICS 4.0.4** so can any help me on finding the ADB driver so i can connect my device and starting using it for testing because in my project some media thing which are not allowed in emulator or if not that any other device adb driver which is compatible to my device.Thanks and i will upvote for any kind of replies.

Answer (score 0):

SPICE is an Indian mobile manufacturer. The following link contains tools related to Mi-425 phone with description. Search for "ADB and other Drivers from SPICE CD" in the post.
I hope it works...

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1742545

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://adbdriver.com/downloads/ (I used that to install ADB drivers for Wiko Wax)